# git: create results of another disconnected commit

Tags: git

Let's say I have git repo with two disconnected root commits, referenced by branches `master` and `new`. I'd like to create a commit on `master` making that branch identical to the `new` commit. That is, looking like:

`* "new" changes   <- master
 |
 * Initial commit`

such that

`git diff master new`

is empty.

- I don't want a merge commit of `master` and `new`.
- I know the exact state I want to end up in, so I shouldn't need to figure out merge conflicts.

How?

---

#### TLDR answer

`git read-tree --reset -u new
git commit -m "new commit"`

For more info, see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43813981/45813), and *even* more, see [Edmundo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43812988/1256452) and comments therein.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is not equivalent to cherry-picking `new`, which would amount to *adding* the difference between the empty tree and commit `new` to your current state. For instance if your current state has file `foo` (only) and you were to cherry-pick `new` that has file `bar` (only), you would get both foo *and* bar as your new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edmundo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43812988/1256452) is one of the shortest ways to do this.  Another shortest way to do it is, while on branch `master`, to use `git read-tree --reset -u new` followed by `git commit` to make a new commit.  Note that `git read-tree --reset -u` will wreck any in-progress work (a la `git reset --hard`) so be sure that you are not in the middle of something first.

Unfortunately all short and easy ways involve using some of the not-really-meant-for-humans "plumbing" commands like `git commit-tree` or `git read-tree`.  The main advantage to `git read-tree` over `git commit-tree` is that the latter is a more strict bondage-and-discipline type command, requiring that you specify the tree hash ID directly (e.g., `new^{tree}`) rather than just a commit ID that resolves to a tree.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for why `new^{tree}` works here.  (And, of course, you must also provide the hash ID of the `master` commit, though just `master` works there.)

The longer and uglier way that uses only "normal" commands is `git rm -rf .` followed by `git checkout new -- .` followed by `git commit`: basically "remove everything" then "extract all from new" then commit. This must be run at the top of the work-tree.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a single commit to be created on top of master that makes the working tree be the way it is at **new**, you can do this: get the object ID for the tree on new (`git cat-file -p new`). Once you have the **id** of the tree, create a new revision using master as the parent with commit-tree:

`git commit-tree -p master -m "Here's a new revision" <id-of-tree>`

This will give you the ID of the new revision. You can then checkout master and reset --hard to the revision or create a new branch on it.

Comment: This is the shortest, easiest way to do it. Unfortunately all short and easy ways involve using some of the not-really-meant-for-humans "plumbing" commands like this. Another also shortest way to do it is, while on `master`, to use `git read-tree --reset -u new^{tree}` followed by `git commit` to make a new commit. The longer (and uglier) way that uses only "normal" commands is `git rm -rf .` followed by `git checkout new -- .` followed by `git commit`: basically "remove everything" then "extract all from new" then commit. (This must be run at the top of the work-tree.)

Comment: Don't even need the tree id, just "new" or however you'd ordinarily refer to that commit will do.

Comment: Just tried. Providing an object that is not a tree fails miserably.

Comment: I just tried `git read-tree --reset -u new; git commit` and it sure seemed like it worked.

Comment: Oh, that's with one of the recipes provided by @torek. I'm glad.

Comment: Thanks all, gotta get into the deep git knowledge now! @torek: If you want to make that an answer, I'd be happy to check mark it. Seems like the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout new
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge new
```

If you want your `master` state to be identical to `new`, the quickest thing to do is just:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard new
```

Comment: At a minimum, requires figuring out merge conflicts, which I shouldn't need to do. To be fair, I added that requirement after your answer.

Comment: Not sure I follow your question, but I edited my answer with what I _think_ you're after.

Comment: The second proposal (checkout then reset --hard) is not what Clay asked for because that means losing master history. A revision _after_ the current position of master is what's wanted.